# Selector for class prefix inside another class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to know what the proper selector is for the example below

```
<span class="A">
   <span class="B_C"></span>
   <span class="B_D"></span>
<span>
```

I want to select all the classes starting with `B_` nested inside of `A`. I have tried each of these, but none of them worked:

```
.A + [class^="B_"], .A + [class*=" B_"]
.A > [class^="B_"], .A > [class*=" B_"]
.A [class^="B_"], .A [class*=" B_"]
```

Comment: `.A [class^=B_] { /* styles */}` *should* have worked.

Comment: @DavidThomas you are right...my bad....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.A [class^="B_"]` works. Typically you'd put that attribute selector with another element though, like `.A span[class^="B_"]` (which also works).

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image: output]

#### CSS:

```css
.A [class^="B_"] {
    color: red;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<span class="A">
   <span class="B_C">B_C</span>
   <span class="B_D">B_D</span>
   <span class="C_D">C_D</span>
<span>
```

Comment: I love that you took the time to craft a special JS Fiddle button. Oh, and +1 for being right, too. =)

Answer (score 3):

An Element can have multiple classes so you can make it much easier if you just select by class:

```
<span class="A">
   <span class="class_b class_c"></span>
   <span class="class_b class_d"></span>
<span>
```

you can select all class that have `b`:

```
.A .class_b
```

Comment: +1 This is a *better* technique, but not how you would select classes *starting with* the letter b followed by an underscore. I wouldn't even say necessarily "better", but it is a clearer way of doing it.